# Configure vsftpd to chown uploaded files

Tags: permissions, ftp, vsftpd

I have vsftpd up and running on my Ubuntu server. This is a development server and I want to be able to FTP my code directly to the directory which Apache is serving out.

As most of you know, www-data is the Apache user and the www-data user needs to have permissions to the directory that Apache is serving out.

I didn't want to make www-data an FTP user as well, so what I did instead was create another user for use with FTP, and put both www-data and the new user in a new group called www.

I did a `chown -R www-data:www *` to the directory that Apache is serving and it works mostly fine.

The issue comes in when I FTP upload a file that didn't previously exist in that directory. The owner gets set to my FTP user. I want the owner to get set to www-data and the group to get set to www whenever a new file gets uploaded.

Is there any way to do this with vsftpd?

I've been furiously googling around for hours, but I can't find a way to do it. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Edit:

I just set up a couple of cron jobs to run every minute and set the permissions:

`*/1 * * * * chown -R www-data:www /var/www`

`*/1 * * * * chmod -R g+rw /var/www`

It works but it's kind of clunky, and there's a ~1 minute delay between me uploading new code and having it work when I hit F5 in my browser.

Answer (score -1):

Read `man 2 chmod`, especially the part that says:

```
   S_ISGID  (02000)  set-group-ID (set process effective group ID on execve(2); mandatory locking, as described in  fcntl(2);  take  a
                     new file's group from parent directory, as described in chown(2) and mkdir(2))
```

You could probably use this to make all files created in the directory in the `www` group, and change your web server's `umask` value to `022`

To do this safely, read and reread `man 2 chmod`, `man 2 open`, `man 2 stat` and anything pointed to in the **See Also:** sections. Learn how Linux deals with file and directory permissions for fun and/or profit!

Or, you could install `inoticoming - trigger actions when files hit an incoming directory`, and do your thing whenever a file hits.